# I couldn't create AdMob banner in my Xamarin.ios

Tags: ios, firebase, xamarin.ios, admob

I'm trying to add AdMob banner in my Xamarin iOS project. You can see my code below.

```
public void AddAdvirtesement()
        {
            var adView = new BannerView();

            adView.Frame = new CGRect(0, View.Bounds.Height - 50, View.Bounds.Width, 50);

            adView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Gray;

            adView.AdUnitID = bannerId;

            adView.RootViewController = this;

            View.AddSubview(adView);

            var request = Request.GetDefaultRequest();

            string[] testdevices = new string[2];

            //testdevices[0] = Request.SimulatorId.ToString();
            //testdevices[1] = "b5f64ec8566bf1a5cd1cb853d7106aa7";

            request.TestDevices = testdevices;

            adView.LoadRequest(request);
        }
```

i get this output above code:

> 2016-12-11 22:25:42.659 betcluev4[9220:627724]  You are
>   currently using version 7.11.0 of the SDK. Please consider updating
>   your SDK to the most recent SDK version to get the latest features and
>   bug fixes. The latest SDK can be downloaded from .......

but I already have the latest SDK of Firebase (7.11.0). Any thoughts?

Comment: is there any volunteer for help:)

Comment: the issue is the warning message or something else?

Comment: i get this warning message and the banner doesn't show. My main problem is the banner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the plist [configurations](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/firebaseiosadmob) for FireBase that are needed in your project , and the sample code below

> Configurations

Once you have your GoogleService-Info.plist file downloaded in your computer, do the following steps in Xamarin Studio:

Add `GoogleService-Info.plist` file to your app project.

Set `GoogleService-Info.plist` build action behaviour to `Bundle Resource` by Right clicking/Build Action.

Open `GoogleService-Info.plist` file and change `IS_ADS_ENABLED` value to `Yes`.

Add the following line of code somewhere in your app, typically in your AppDelegate's `FinishedLaunching` method (don't forget to import `Firebase.Analytics` namespace):

```
App.Configure ();
```

> Sample Code

```
using Google.MobileAds;
const string bannerId = "<Get your ID at google.com/ads/admob>";

BannerView adView;
bool viewOnScreen = false;

public void AddBanner ()
{
    // Setup your BannerView, review AdSizeCons class for more Ad sizes. 
    adView = new BannerView (size: AdSizeCons.Banner, origin: new CGPoint (0, 0)) {
        AdUnitID = bannerId,
        RootViewController = this
    };
// Wire AdReceived event to know when the Ad is ready to be displayed
adView.AdReceived += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
    if (!viewOnScreen) {
        View.AddSubview (adView);
        viewOnScreen = true;
    }
};

var request = Request.GetDefaultRequest ();
// Requests test ads on devices you specify. Your test device ID is printed to the console when
// an ad request is made. GADBannerView automatically returns test ads when running on a
// simulator. After you get your device ID, add it here
request.TestDevices = new [] { Request.SimulatorId.ToString () };

// Request an ad
adView.LoadRequest (request);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i think you send getting start document of xamarin (https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/firebaseiosadmob) but it's not working:( did you do it brefore? if you have any sample I would like to see it.

Comment: yes thats the official sample from xamarin . Have you tried that?

Comment: hey @iamclarus, i finally did this, the code i was sharing was okay, i need another thing, one of them add keychain_sharing node in my info.plist. and another thing is edit the adsense payment method.
Thanks for your helps.

Comment: @KaanAkyalçın glad its now sorted